# setTimeout not working as expected React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, settimeout

I am trying to call a function after 40 seconds in React native. But it seems no matter what time I set the function calls within 15 to 18 seconds. Have tried several solution but hard luck.

My full code is given below:

```
export default class OpenLocker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      disable: false,
    }
  }

  openBox() {
    const data = {
      model: this.props.model,
      machine_id: this.props.machine_id,
      locker_id: this.props.locker_id,
    }

    const { model, machine_id, locker_id } = data

    const this_url = window.location.href
    const parse_url = url.parse(this_url, true, true)
    const host = parse_url.protocol + "//" + parse_url.host
    const api_url = `${host}/vendor/locker/open/${model}/${machine_id}/${locker_id}`

    axios
      .get(api_url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.data) {
          alert("Box open failed!")
        } else {
          this.setState({
            disable: true,
          })
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.closeBox(data, host).bind(this)
          }, 40000)
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
      })
  }

  closeBox(data, host) {
    const { model, machine_id, locker_id } = data
    const api_url = `${host}/vendor/locker/close/${model}/${machine_id}/${locker_id}`

    axios
      .get(api_url)
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.data) {
          alert("Box close failed!")
        } else {
          this.setState({
            disable: false,
          })

          alert("Box opened successfully")
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error)
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          disabled={this.state.disable}
          id="open-box"
          type="button"
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-block text-white"
          onClick={this.openBox.bind(this)}
        >
          Open Box
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

How to call the function `closeBox` after 40 seconds or why setTimeout() not working the way I expect? Need your suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mplungjan can you please be more specific ??

Comment: Oops. I see you do bind (this) - reopened

Comment: Thanks . do u have any suggestion how to make it work??

Comment: Where is (data,host) defined. You do not seem to store response.data in data

Comment: So `this.closeBox(response.data, host).bind(this);` assuming host is defined elsewhere

Comment: But still check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/38931751/295783 in case you are not handling `this` correctly

Comment: Need more code, the problem is somewhere else. No matter what the value of `this` is, it won't cause the timer delay to arbitrarily change to some other value.

Comment: @GuyIncognito I have included full code. please have a look again.